# D-Bus and Systemd Issues with Podman on CentOS Stream 9

Tags: centos, systemd, dbus, podman

I am using Podman version 4.8.1 on CentOS Stream 9 as a non-root user "apideployer". I encounter an error when trying to load systemd user services with "systemctl --user daemon-reload", receiving "Failed to connect to bus: No medium found". This seems to be related to D-Bus access within my SSH session.

I attempted to transition to Quadlet files for better container management, but I'm encountering issues with the systemd integration. I expected systemd to generate .service files from the Quadlet files, but this isn’t happening. I have placed the .container file at $HOME/.config/containers/systemd/

I have been reviewing:

- https://docs.podman.io/en/v4.8.2/markdown/podman-systemd.unit.5.html
- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/quadlet-podman

This is one of my Quadlet files for testing purposes. The oracle-db.container:

```
[Unit]
Description=Oracle Database Container
After=network.target

[Container]
Name=oracle-db
Image=container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:latest
Environment=ORACLE_PWD=mysecurepassword
Ports=1521:1521
Volume= oracle-db.volume:/opt/oracle/oradata
Network=oracle-db.network
IP=192.168.100.10

[Service]
# Restart service when sleep finishes
Restart=always
# Extend Timeout to allow time to pull the image
TimeoutStartSec=900

[Install]
# Start by default on boot
WantedBy=multi-user.target default.target
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Please delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected systemd to generate .service files from the Quadlet files, but this isn’t happening.

Note that generators only run at boot time and after running `systemctl daemon-reload`. You will find the generated unit files in `/run/systemd/generator`. They will run automatically at boot, or you can explicitly `systemctl start` the generated service.

If it looks like the unit files aren't getting generated, you can manually run the generator:

```
mkdir /tmp/units
/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/podman-system-generator -v -no-kmsg-log /tmp/units
```

This will output some information about the generation process. E.g., on my system, the above produces:

```
quadlet-generator[270888]: Starting quadlet-generator, output to: /tmp/units
quadlet-generator[270888]: Loading source unit file /etc/containers/systemd/devpi.container
quadlet-generator[270888]: Loading source unit file /etc/containers/systemd/devpi.volume
quadlet-generator[270888]: Loading source unit file /etc/containers/systemd/services.network
quadlet-generator[270888]: Loading source unit file /etc/containers/systemd/traefik.container
quadlet-generator[270888]: Loading source unit file /etc/containers/systemd/whoami.container
quadlet-generator[270888]: writing "/tmp/units/devpi-volume.service"
quadlet-generator[270888]: writing "/tmp/units/services-network.service"
quadlet-generator[270888]: writing "/tmp/units/devpi.service"
quadlet-generator[270888]: Creating symlink /tmp/units/default.target.wants/devpi.service -> ../devpi.service
quadlet-generator[270888]: writing "/tmp/units/traefik.service"
quadlet-generator[270888]: Creating symlink /tmp/units/default.target.wants/traefik.service -> ../traefik.service
quadlet-generator[270888]: writing "/tmp/units/whoami.service"
quadlet-generator[270888]: Creating symlink /tmp/units/default.target.wants/whoami.service -> ../whoami.service
```

This should let you know if there are any errors in your quadlet files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Running the generator as you suggested showed me where I went wrong in my Quadlet files. Fixed that, and it worked! Also, a heads-up: the generated .service files ended up in `/run/user/[UID]/systemd/generator` instead of `/run/systemd/generator`. Just something I noticed for user-level services. Really appreciate your guidance!